# Where can I find a place to sleep near Hinatuan river (Enchanted River)?

Tags: accommodation, philippines, ecotourism

In my next visit to the Philippines I would like to visit Hinatuan river, but it's almost 600km away from the place I'll be staying. I was trying to find a place to sleep near there so I can go to the river in the morning and then drive back, but I don't know if there's any place to stay in that area

This is the place I want to visit:
[image]

Here is some info about the river:
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2429173/Enchanted-ways-Mystery-idyllic-Filipino-river-appears-source.html

Comment: What about the results you get when you search on google or tripadvisor for "hotels hinatuan"?

Comment: @uncovery those results aren't anywhere near the river I mention. In fact, most of them are in a different island like this one: http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g2223522-d1546987-Reviews-Tarzans_Resort-Hinatuan_Surigao_del_Sur_Province_Caraga_Region_Mindanao.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest place that I can find in the area is the town of Bislig, which also has it's own Airpot. There are 3 hotels in the town, all available on [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Tourism-g1956921-Bislig_Mindanao-Vacations.html). From there it's only a [30 minute car ride](http://goo.gl/maps/0o5K6) to the river.

Next closest larger city would be Butuan City, from where it's [1.46 hours to drive](http://goo.gl/maps/B9tYR). There, you do not have more hotels, but the quality seems to be [a bit better](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1568545-d1056046-Reviews-Almont_Inland_Resort-Butuan_Caraga_Region_Mindanao.html).

If you are willing to [drive 3 hours](http://goo.gl/maps/g3Y3y), you can go to Davao City, where you have international Hotel chains and [overall 44 hotels to chose from](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g298459-Davao_City_Davao_Region_Mindanao-Hotels.html).

Comment: thanks for you answer. Just a tip: don't trust google maps' estimates for trips in Philippines. you should add at least 50% because of the roads they have there.. :) Davao is going to be our first stop on the way there.. so we already planned that part. Is the place to stay near the river the one that we need more. Thanks!

Comment: From what I could see on maps and other sources, there is really nothing really close by. Not even a sizeable village.

Comment: That was the idea I had in my head. I'll accept your answer and probably next month I'll put a comment about the experience :)